# Как выбрать записи за вчера/неделю/месяц?

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

приветствую! как выбрать записи за сегодня/вчера/неделю/месяц? в таблице есть поле DATE (date) Y-m-d

пытался делать так:

За вчера

```
SELECT * FROM stat WHERE date >= (CURDATE()-1) AND date < CURDATE()
```

За неделю

```
SELECT * FROM stat WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

За месяц (За 30 дней)

```
SELECT * FROM stat WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

За вчера, выборку делает, а вот за неделю и месяц, не хочет....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
// текущая неделя
SELECT * FROM `stat` WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW()) AND WEEK(`date`) = WEEK(NOW());
// текущий месяц
SELECT * FROM `stat` WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(NOW());
// или за последние 30 дней
SELECT * FROM `stat` WHERE `date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```

Comment: лучше все-таки сравнивать поле (без применения к нему функции) со значением, иначе индекс не будет использоваться никогда. 

* http://hashcode.ru/questions/143061/php-как-сделать-выборку-из-базы-за-эту-неделю
* http://hashcode.ru/questions/320076/php-как-получить-количество-заказов-в-день-неделю-месяц

Comment: чет, у меня ни один ни второй вариант не работал, сделал по другому, повесел два поля с календарями, и поттом запросом вытаскивал нужный мне диапазон

$stat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stat where `data`>='".$data1."' AND `data`<='".$data2."'");

Answer (score 0):

Старайтесь внутри условий выборки никогда не применять функции к столбцу БД, это сильно замедляет работу запроса (он не может использовать индекс). Стройте условия так, чтобы значение из столбца сравнивалось с заранее подготовленными значениями границ.

Исходя из этого для получения данных за текущие день/неделю/месяц нам надо придумать формулы, которые вычислят вчерашний день; понедельник календарной недели с текущим днём и воскресенье календарной недели с текущим днём; последний день месяца.

Таким образом на PHP и Postgres получились такие решения:

За вчера

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date = (CURRENT_DATE - 1)
```

За неделю

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE date between
        CURRENT_DATE - (extract(isodow from CURRENT_DATE)::int - 1)
    and CURRENT_DATE + (7 - extract(isodow from CURRENT_DATE)::int)
```

За месяц

```
$date = new \DateTime();
SELECT *
      FROM my_table
     WHERE date between
            $date->format('Y-m-01')
        and $date->format('Y-m-t')
```